# Why is the Theorem of Sylvester and Schur a generalization of Bertrand's postulate?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, distribution-of-primes

The Theorem of Sylvester and Schur states that for some n>k, one of n+1,...,n+k-1, has a prime divisor exceeding k. While Bertrand's postulate says that for all positive integers n, there exists a prime number between n and 2n.

I see how these are related but I can't make the direct connection between the two, and I'm struggling to understand why Sylvester and Schur's theorem is a generalization of Bertrand's.

Comment: Bertrand's postulate can be recover from Sylvester and Schur's theorem by taking $k=n-1$.

Comment: You misstated the theorem of Sylvester and Schur: it is not *some* $n > k$, but *all* $n > k$: for *all* positive integers $k$ and integers $n > k$, at least one of the $k$ integers $n, n+1, \ldots, n+k-1$ is divisible by a prime larger than $k$. When you use $n = k+1$ that means for *all* positive integers $k$, at least one of the integers $k+1, \ldots, 2k$ has a prime factor greater than $k$.  An integer in the range $k+1,\ldots,2k$ with a prime factor that's at least $k+1$ has to be prime.